# How to write a Maven plugin IT test that correctly fails its build, resulting in an overall pass?

Tags: maven, maven-3

When generating a skeleton Maven plugin from archetype, the new project includes a Maven project under the `src/it` directory. It is an integration it (hinted at by the `it` dir name) and fresh out-of-the-box it passes when run during Maven's `integration-test` phase.

There are nearly 10 such IT Maven projects, a subset of which intentionally result in `BUILD FAILURE`, and attendant `verify.groovy` scripts that ensure those builds fail for the correct reason. Ideally each IT test sub-build that fails for the correct reason results in that IT test passing, but by including any of these failing IT tests as part of the whole integration test suite causes the overall Maven run to fail as well, which is incorrect in my case.

How do I coax Maven to run those failing Maven sub-builds, ignore their build results, but honor the results of their Groovy verification scripts?

Edit: One IT test (disabled) is [committed here](https://github.com/vivid-inc/clojure-maven-plugin/tree/release-0.3.0/src/it/clojure.test-fail).

Comment: If you have IT's for a plugin all IT's should be running fine. If they are failing there is an issue.? Based on the usage of maven-invoker-plugin you have to define a `invoker.properties` (http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#invokerPropertiesFile) file in your appropriate IT and  define `invoker.buildResult=failure` which assumes that your build will always and intentionally fails.

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise, `invoker.properties` is the key! If you write this as an answer, I'll accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you like to write an integration test which is intended to fail as a result 
you have to express this via the `invoker.properties` file like this:

```
invoker.buildResult=failure
```

The full description of the file can be found in [the documentation](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-invoker-plugin/run-mojo.html#invokerPropertiesFile).